# LibGdx Collisions

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, collision

I'm currently working on my first Android game project using LibGdx. It is a 2D maze game where you use touch input to "draw" a line from one of the entrances to one of the exits. The world itself is a TiledMap, which act only as a visual backround at the moment.

The problem I have is the whole system of collision detection. There are (obliviously) walls in the maze, located on the edges of my background tiles. So when I slide my finger across a wall, the "player line" should stop at the wall. Additionally, events should be triggered when the line reaches an exit.

I could not find a way to properly implement these functionalities using the built-in libraries (I tried using Scene2D and Box2D). Stopping an actor's movement and firing an event is not that exotic, or?

All I need is some information on what I should use and maybe some first steps. :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just detect which tiles the user pressed and if there is a wall in between two tiles, you will not add the last tile to the path

Comment: @noone
I was thinking of that too. But for the sake of a better game experience, I wanted the player line to be able to move "freely" inside the tiles. That's why I need the collision detection.

A simple mockup which hopefully helps understanding what I mean:
[Mockup](http://i.imgur.com/qFlpfi7.png)

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collision detection is probably the most difficult part of making a tiled game. Libgdx has a lot of useful methods to help you **get the geometry** but the actual collision handling after a collision is detected (called collision resolution) is a large topic. I suspect all you want is the player to stop. More advanced realistic solutions such as bouncing and friction are what Box2D specializes in.

First and foremost, getting the geometry that's going to collide.

a) The player can be represented by a rectangle. Have it extend the Sprite class and then you can use the getBoundingRectangle() function (A rectangle keeps things simple, but there are many other shapes that get used for collisions ).

b) Getting the geometry of the tiles, also a bunch of rectangles. 
A function that gets the surrounding tiles.

```
    public void getsurroundingTiles(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, Array<Rectangle> surroundingTiles){



    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) worldRef.getCurrentMap().getLayers().get("Terrain");
    surroundingTiles.clear();
    for (int y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
        for (int x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
               Cell cell = layer.getCell(x, y);
            if (cell != null && cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked")) {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.set(x, y, 1, 1);
                surroundingTiles.add(rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This function gets the tiled map tile layer made in the Tiled program and fills up a Rectangle ArrayList with the rectangles only if the tile has the key "blocked".

So now you have rectangles representing your player, and representing all the 
colliding blocks. You can draw them with a ShapeRenderer object. 
This is what it looks like in a game I am working on.

[image: simple platformer]

Lastly, actually resolving the collisions is a larger topic. This is a great starting point. 
http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html

Comment: I solved this problem before seeing your answer, but it helped me achieving a better solution in a new projekt. So I accepted it now, thank you!